# Create new mailboxes using a CSV via Powershell in Office 365

Tags: powershell, office365

I need to create new mailboxes via Powershell in Office 365.
I am using this script:

```
$User = "administrator@blablabla.onmicrosoft.com" 
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String "P@ssword1"
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $User, $PWord
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $Credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection 
Import-PSSession $Session

Import-CSV new.csv | foreach { 
    New-Mailbox -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -displayname $_.DisplayName -password (ConvertTo-SecureString $_.password -AsPlainText -Force) -usagelocation "us" 
}

Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Details of mailboxes are saved in new.csv file.
See the following example:

```
UserPrincipalName,DisplayName,password
clark.kent@blablabla.onmicrosoft.com,Clark Kent,P@ssword1
bruce.wayne@blablabla.onmicrosoft.com,Bruce Wayne,P@ssword1
peter.parker@blablabla.onmicrosoft.com,Peter Parker,P@ssword1
```

When I run this script, I return error:

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'UserPrincipalName'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Mailbox], 

ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,New-Mailbox
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Please, what is wrong?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UPN Parameter is only available on the Exchange on-premises. Depending on on whether your AD is on-premises or in the cloud, I would suggest creating the AD account first with this parameter and then enable the mailbox.

Or just don't use this parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to do this is by doing this via **MicrosoftOnlineServicesID** parameter which seems to replicate **UPN**.

```
New-Mailbox -Alias $mailbox.Alias -Name $mailbox.Name -DisplayName $mailbox.DisplayName -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $true -Password $temporaryPassword -MicrosoftOnlineServicesID $upn -WhatIf

WARNING: After you create a new mailbox, you must go to the Office 365 Admin Center and assign the mailbox a license, or it will
 be disabled after the grace period.
What if: Creating mailbox "Anna" with User Principal Name "anna@domain.org.pl" in organizational
 unit "EURPR06A004.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations/domain.onmicrosoft.com".
```

Full story can be found at my [blog](https://evotec.pl/office-365-parameter-cannot-found-matches-parameter-name-userprincipalname-new-mailbox/) but all you need is to change **UPN** to **MicrosoftOnlineServicesID** and it should work right away.

Answer (score 0):

Try -identity instead of -userprincipalname

Comment: It won't work. Only MicrosoftOnlineServicesID works in this case.